# how to disable tap in perfect scrollbar.js

Tags: javascript, ipad, perfect-scrollbar

When I first-click on content using perfect scollbar it render me to top of content and rest of time it is not responding.

I want to disable that click event and tap shouldn't work on it.

Comment: $('.ps-container').scrollTop(608).perfectScrollbar('update');

after this code the scroll content and scroll bar set at 608 px but when i click on the content it will reset to 0px position.I guess it is default functionality of perfect scrollbar. but i want to remove it .please download perfect scrollbar and check the code

Comment: please edit your question and add the info from the comment you just added